# Flutter app(iOS ) does not run on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I have the following problem with a build stage of the Flutter app in Xcode.
Trying to run a project inside a Android Studio I have faced some problems with a running project for iOS. As I see my project is builded in Xcode correctly and fully. But in a deployment fase on a iOS simulator the error happens due to some script(**Command PhaseScriptExecution **).

```
Changing current working directory to: /Users/fele/Documents/NewFlutterVersion
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 7 Plus in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                           14,9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/fele/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.15.1/darwin/Classes/AudioplayersPlugin.m:88:37: warning: incompatible pointer types sending 'FlutterEngine *' to parameter of type
    'NSObject<FlutterBinaryMessenger> * _Nonnull' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                        binaryMessenger:_headlessEngine];
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'Flutter' imported from /Users/fele/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/audioplayers-0.15.1/darwin/Classes/AudioplayersPlugin.h:2:
    /Users/fele/Documents/NewFlutterVersion/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterChannels.h:178:74: note: passing argument to parameter 'messenger' here
                          binaryMessenger:(NSObject<FlutterBinaryMessenger>*)messenger;
                                                                             ^
    1 warning generated.
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.3/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:92:3: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
      PictureStream();
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.3/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
    abstract class PictureStreamCompleter extends Diagnosticable {
                   ^

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

Here is an error log from Xcode where this error is more detailed described.
´´´

```
        PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
            export ALTERNATE_GROUP\=171418436
            export ALTERNATE_MODE\=u+w,go-w,a+rX
            export ALTERNATE_OWNER\=fele
            export ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES\=YES
            export ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS\=NO
            export ALWAYS_USE_SEPARATE_HEADERMAPS\=NO
            export APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Developer
            export APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR\=/AppleInternal
            export APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Documentation
            export APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Library
            export APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS\=/AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
            export APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY\=NO
            export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES\=NO
            export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_HEADERS\=NO
            export ARCHS\=x86_64
            export ARCHS_STANDARD\=arm64\ x86_64\ i386
            export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT\=arm64\ i386\ x86_64
            export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT\=i386
            export ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT\=arm64\ x86_64
            export ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT\=arm64\ x86_64\ i386
            export ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS\=arm64\ i386\ x86_64
            export ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME\=AppIcon
            export ASSETCATALOG_FILTER_FOR_DEVICE_MODEL\=iPod9,1
            export ASSETCATALOG_FILTER_FOR_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\=14.2
            export AVAILABLE_PLATFORMS\=appletvos\ appletvsimulator\ iphoneos\ iphonesimulator\ macosx\ watchos\ watchsimulator
            export AppIdentifierPrefix\=B5787S6HFP.
            export BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE\=marker
            export BUILD_ACTIVE_RESOURCES_ONLY\=YES
            export BUILD_COMPONENTS\=headers\ build
            export BUILD_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products
            export BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION\=NO
            export BUILD_ROOT\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products
            export BUILD_STYLE\=
            export BUILD_VARIANTS\=normal
            export BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
            export BUNDLE_CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH_deep\=Contents/
            export BUNDLE_EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_NAME_deep\=MacOS
            export BUNDLE_FORMAT\=shallow
            export BUNDLE_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH\=Frameworks
            export BUNDLE_PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH\=PlugIns
            export BUNDLE_PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH\=PrivateHeaders
            export BUNDLE_PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH\=Headers
            export CACHE_ROOT\=/var/folders/4w/9zphcz4d2n7bfcgj6l_s4k2wlj7yt1/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/12.2-12B45b/Xcode
            export CCHROOT\=/var/folders/4w/9zphcz4d2n7bfcgj6l_s4k2wlj7yt1/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/12.2-12B45b/Xcode
            export CHMOD\=/bin/chmod
            export CHOWN\=/usr/sbin/chown
            export CLANG_ANALYZER_LOCALIZABILITY_NONLOCALIZED\=YES
            export CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL\=YES
            export CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD\=gnu++0x
            export CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY\=libc++
            export CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES\=YES
            export CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC\=YES
            export CLANG_MODULES_BUILD_SESSION_FILE\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation
            export CLANG_WARN_BLOCK_CAPTURE_AUTORELEASING\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_BOOL_CONVERSION\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_COMMA\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_CONSTANT_CONVERSION\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_DEPRECATED_OBJC_IMPLEMENTATIONS\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE\=YES_ERROR
            export CLANG_WARN_EMPTY_BODY\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_ENUM_CONVERSION\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_INFINITE_RECURSION\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_INT_CONVERSION\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_NON_LITERAL_NULL_CONVERSION\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_IMPLICIT_RETAIN_SELF\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_LITERAL_CONVERSION\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_OBJC_ROOT_CLASS\=YES_ERROR
            export CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER\=NO
            export CLANG_WARN_RANGE_LOOP_ANALYSIS\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_STRICT_PROTOTYPES\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_SUSPICIOUS_MOVE\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN_UNREACHABLE_CODE\=YES
            export CLANG_WARN__DUPLICATE_METHOD_MATCH\=YES
            export CLASS_FILE_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/JavaClasses
            export CLEAN_PRECOMPS\=YES
            export CLONE_HEADERS\=NO
            export CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app
            export CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED\=YES
            export CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED\=YES
            export CODE_SIGN_CONTEXT_CLASS\=XCiPhoneSimulatorCodeSignContext
            export CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY\=-
            export CODE_SIGN_INJECT_BASE_ENTITLEMENTS\=YES
            export COLOR_DIAGNOSTICS\=NO
            export COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES\=NO
            export COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE\=Default
            export COMPOSITE_SDK_DIRS\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CompositeSDKs
            export COMPRESS_PNG_FILES\=YES
            export CONFIGURATION\=Debug
            export CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
            export CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator
            export CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app
            export COPYING_PRESERVES_HFS_DATA\=NO
            export COPY_HEADERS_RUN_UNIFDEF\=NO
            export COPY_PHASE_STRIP\=NO
            export COPY_RESOURCES_FROM_STATIC_FRAMEWORKS\=YES
            export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_PLATFORM_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
            export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\=iphoneos
            export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_SDK_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.2.sdk
            export CORRESPONDING_DEVICE_SDK_NAME\=iphoneos14.2
            export CP\=/bin/cp
            export CREATE_INFOPLIST_SECTION_IN_BINARY\=NO
            export CURRENT_ARCH\=undefined_arch
            export CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION\=5
            export CURRENT_VARIANT\=normal
            export DART_OBFUSCATION\=false
            export DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING\=YES
            export DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS\=YES
            export DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT\=dwarf
            export DEFAULT_COMPILER\=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
            export DEFAULT_DEXT_INSTALL_PATH\=/System/Library/DriverExtensions
            export DEFAULT_KEXT_INSTALL_PATH\=/System/Library/Extensions
            export DEFINES_MODULE\=NO
            export DEPLOYMENT_LOCATION\=NO
            export DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING\=NO
            export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_ENV_NAME\=IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
            export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_FLAG_NAME\=mios-simulator-version-min
            export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_FLAG_PREFIX\=-mios-simulator-version-min\=
            export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_LD_ENV_NAME\=IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
            export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_LD_FLAG_NAME\=ios_simulator_version_min
            export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SETTING_NAME\=IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
            export DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_SUGGESTED_VALUES\=9.0\ 9.1\ 9.2\ 9.3\ 10.0\ 10.1\ 10.2\ 10.3\ 11.0\ 11.1\ 11.2\ 11.3\ 11.4\ 12.0\ 12.1\ 12.2\ 12.3\ 12.4\ 13.0\ 13.1\ 13.2\ 13.3\ 13.4\ 13.5\ 13.6\ 14.0\ 14.1\ 14.2
            export DERIVED_FILES_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/DerivedSources
            export DERIVED_FILE_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/DerivedSources
            export DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/DerivedSources
            export DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications
            export DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
            export DEVELOPER_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
            export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
            export DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR_QUOTED\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
            export DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library
            export DEVELOPER_SDK_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs
            export DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Tools
            export DEVELOPER_USR_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr
            export DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE\=English
            export DEVELOPMENT_TEAM\=B5787S6HFP
            export DOCUMENTATION_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/English.lproj/Documentation
            export DONT_GENERATE_INFOPLIST_FILE\=NO
            export DO_HEADER_SCANNING_IN_JAM\=NO
            export DSTROOT\=/tmp/Runner.dst
            export DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
            export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME\=Runner.app.dSYM
            export DWARF_DSYM_FILE_SHOULD_ACCOMPANY_PRODUCT\=NO
            export DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
            export EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME\=-iphonesimulator
            export EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT\=NO
            export EMBED_ASSET_PACKS_IN_PRODUCT_BUNDLE\=NO
            export ENABLE_BITCODE\=NO
            export ENABLE_DEFAULT_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS\=YES
            export ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME\=NO
            export ENABLE_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES\=YES
            export ENABLE_ON_DEMAND_RESOURCES\=YES
            export ENABLE_PREVIEWS\=NO
            export ENABLE_STRICT_OBJC_MSGSEND\=YES
            export ENABLE_TESTABILITY\=YES
            export ENABLE_TESTING_SEARCH_PATHS\=NO
            export ENTITLEMENTS_DESTINATION\=__entitlements
            export ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED\=YES
            export EXCLUDED_INSTALLSRC_SUBDIRECTORY_PATTERNS\=.DS_Store\ .svn\ .git\ .hg\ CVS
            export EXCLUDED_RECURSIVE_SEARCH_PATH_SUBDIRECTORIES\=\*.nib\ \*.lproj\ \*.framework\ \*.gch\ \*.xcode\*\ \*.xcassets\ \(\*\)\ .DS_Store\ CVS\ .svn\ .git\ .hg\ \*.pbproj\ \*.pbxproj
            export EXECUTABLES_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/Executables
            export EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app
            export EXECUTABLE_NAME\=Runner
            export EXECUTABLE_PATH\=Runner.app/Runner
            export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY\=-
            export EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME\=-
            export FILE_LIST\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects/LinkFileList
            export FIXED_FILES_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/FixedFiles
            export FLUTTER_BUILD_DIR\=build
            export FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME\=1.0.0
            export FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER\=1
            export FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR\=/Users/fele/Developer/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios
            export FLUTTER_ROOT\=/Users/fele/Developer/flutter
            export FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/Frameworks
            export FRAMEWORK_FLAG_PREFIX\=-framework
            export FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator\ \ \"/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher\"\ \"/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac\"\ \"/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf\"\ \"/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/audioplayers\"\ \"/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/camera\"\ \"/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/flutter_local_notifications\"\ \"/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/native_device_orientation\"\ \"/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/path_provider\"\ \"/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/qr_mobile_vision\"\ \"/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared_preferences\"\ 
            export FRAMEWORK_VERSION\=A
            export FULL_PRODUCT_NAME\=Runner.app
            export GCC3_VERSION\=3.3
            export GCC_C_LANGUAGE_STANDARD\=gnu99
            export GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC\=NO
            export GCC_INLINES_ARE_PRIVATE_EXTERN\=YES
            export GCC_NO_COMMON_BLOCKS\=YES
            export GCC_OBJC_LEGACY_DISPATCH\=YES
            export GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL\=0
            export GCC_PFE_FILE_C_DIALECTS\=c\ objective-c\ c++\ objective-c++
            export GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS\=DEBUG\=1\ \ COCOAPODS\=1\ DEBUG\=1\ \ GPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS\=1
            export GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN\=NO
            export GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS\=NO
            export GCC_VERSION\=com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0
            export GCC_VERSION_IDENTIFIER\=com_apple_compilers_llvm_clang_1_0
            export GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION\=YES
            export GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE\=YES_ERROR
            export GCC_WARN_UNDECLARED_SELECTOR\=YES
            export GCC_WARN_UNINITIALIZED_AUTOS\=YES_AGGRESSIVE
            export GCC_WARN_UNUSED_FUNCTION\=YES
            export GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE\=YES
            export GENERATED_MODULEMAP_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/GeneratedModuleMaps-iphonesimulator
JAVA_APP_STUB\=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
            export JAVA_ARCHIVE_CLASSES\=YES
            METAL_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app
            export MODULES_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/Modules
            export MODULE_CACHE_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex
            export MTL_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO\=YES
            export NATIVE_ARCH\=x86_64
            export NATIVE_ARCH_32_BIT\=i386
            export NATIVE_ARCH_64_BIT\=x86_64
            export NATIVE_ARCH_ACTUAL\=x86_64
            export NO_COMMON\=YES
            export OBJC_ABI_VERSION\=2
            export OBJECT_FILE_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects
            export OBJECT_FILE_DIR_normal\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal
            export OBJROOT\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex
            export ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH\=YES
            export OS\=MACOS
            export OSAC\=/usr/bin/osacompile
            export OTHER_LDFLAGS\=\ -ObjC\ -l\"c++\"\ -l\"sqlite3\"\ -l\"z\"\ -framework\ \"AVFoundation\"\ -framework\ \"Accelerate\"\ -framework\ \"BarcodeDetector\"\ -framework\ \"CoreGraphics\"\ -framework\ \"CoreImage\"\ -framework\ \"CoreMedia\"\ -framework\ \"CoreVideo\"\ -framework\ \"Flutter\"\ -framework\ \"Foundation\"\ -framework\ \"GTMSessionFetcher\"\ -framework\ \"GoogleMobileVision\"\ -framework\ \"GoogleToolboxForMac\"\ -framework\ \"LocalAuthentication\"\ -framework\ \"Protobuf\"\ -framework\ \"Security\"\ -framework\ \"UIKit\"\ -framework\ \"audioplayers\"\ -framework\ \"camera\"\ -framework\ \"flutter_local_notifications\"\ -framework\ \"native_device_orientation\"\ -framework\ \"path_provider\"\ -framework\ \"qr_mobile_vision\"\ -framework\ \"shared_preferences\"\ -framework\ \"vibration\"\ -framework\ Flutter
            export OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS\=\ -D\ COCOAPODS
            export PACKAGE_CONFIG\=.packages
            export PACKAGE_TYPE\=com.apple.package-type.wrapper.application
            export PASCAL_STRINGS\=YES
            export PATH\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/libexec:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/local/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
            export PATH_PREFIXES_EXCLUDED_FROM_HEADER_DEPENDENCIES\=/usr/include\ /usr/local/include\ /System/Library/Frameworks\ /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Headers\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/SDKs\ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms
            export PBDEVELOPMENTPLIST_PATH\=Runner.app/pbdevelopment.plist
            export PER_ARCH_OBJECT_FILE_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal/undefined_arch
            export PER_VARIANT_OBJECT_FILE_DIR\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Objects-normal
            export PKGINFO_FILE_PATH\=/Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/PkgInfo
            export PKGINFO_PATH\=Runner.app/PkgInfo
            export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_APPLICATIONS_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications
            export PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_BIN_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin
    PLATFORM_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
            export PLATFORM_DISPLAY_NAME\=iOS\ Simulator
            export PLATFORM_FAMILY_NAME\=iOS
            export PLATFORM_NAME\=iphonesimulator
            export PLATFORM_PREFERRED_ARCH\=x86_64
            export PLATFORM_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION\=18B79
            export PLIST_FILE_OUTPUT_FORMAT\=binary
            export PLUGINS_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/PlugIns
            export PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS\=NO
            export PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/PrivateHeaders
    
    SDK_DIR_iphonesimulator14_2\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.2.sdk
            export SDK_NAME\=iphonesimulator14.2
            export SDK_NAMES\=iphonesimulator14.2
            export SDK_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION\=18B79
            export SDK_VERSION\=14.2
            export SDK_VERSION_ACTUAL\=140200
            export SDK_VERSION_MAJOR\=140000
            export SDK_VERSION_MINOR\=200
            export SED\=/usr/bin/sed
            export SEPARATE_STRIP\=NO
            export SEPARATE_SYMBOL_EDIT\=NO
            export SET_DIR_MODE_OWNER_GROUP\=YES
            export SET_FILE_MODE_OWNER_GROUP\=NO
            export SHALLOW_BUNDLE\=YES
            export SUPPORTS_TEXT_BASED_API\=NO
            export SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER\=Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h
            export SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL\=-Onone
            export SWIFT_PLATFORM_TARGET_PREFIX\=ios
            export SYSTEM_ADMIN_APPS_DIR\=/Applications/Utilities
            export SYSTEM_APPS_DIR\=/Applications
            export SYSTEM_CORE_SERVICES_DIR\=/System/Library/CoreServices
            export SYSTEM_DEMOS_DIR\=/Applications/ExtrasReference\ Library
    
            export VERSION_INFO_BUILDER\=fele
            export VERSION_INFO_FILE\=Runner_vers.c
            export VERSION_INFO_STRING\=\"@\(\#\)PROGRAM:Runner\ \ PROJECT:Runner-5\"
            export WRAPPER_EXTENSION\=app
            export WRAPPER_NAME\=Runner.app
            export WRAPPER_SUFFIX\=.app
            export WRAP_ASSET_PACKS_IN_SEPARATE_DIRECTORIES\=NO
            export XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR\=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode
            export XCODE_PRODUCT_BUILD_VERSION\=12B45b
            export XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL\=1220
            export XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR\=1200
            export XCODE_VERSION_MINOR\=1220
            export XPCSERVICES_FOLDER_PATH\=Runner.app/XPCServices
            export YACC\=yacc
            export arch\=undefined_arch
            export variant\=normal
            /bin/sh -c /Users/fele/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-guvubxvzrewquhbwtsbzkqptqkuu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh
        
        ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.3/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:92:3: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
          PictureStream();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.14.3/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The superclass, 'Diagnosticable', has no unnamed constructor that takes no arguments.
        abstract class PictureStreamCompleter extends Diagnosticable {
                       ^
        
        Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

´´´
I have already updated all dependencies. Checked flutter doctor. Created project from scratch once again with flutter command **flutter create**. But nothing helps.As well I add my Xcode configuration as a screenshot.[Xcode configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Zru.jpg)

How is it possible so solve this problem and run my app in a simulator?
Yours sincerely Fedor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please upgrade your flutter_svg to `flutter_svg: ^0.18.0`.

Answer (score 1):

for me none of these `flutter run`, `flutter build ios`, `arch -x86_64 pod install` and etc does not work until:

1. run `sudo gem install ffi` in terminal.
2. run `arch -x86_64 pod install`
3. then `flutter build ios --release`.

and worked fine.